# How to create custom JSON data structure?

Tags: javascript, json, logic

The output for the JSON data structure with 100 objects should look like this:

```
[{
    "Value": "Sens1_001",
    "Parent": Null,
    "Child": {
        "Value": "Sens2_068",
        "Parent":"Sens1_001",
        "Child" : {
            "Value": "Sens3_034",
            "Parent": "Sen2_068",
            "Child": null,
            "z_cordinate": 5
                  },
        "z_cordinate": 0
            },
        "z_cordonate": -5
    },
{
    "Value": "Sens1_002",
    "Parent": Null,
    "Child": {
        "Value": "Sens2_037",
        "Parent":"Sens1_002",
        "Child" : {
            "Value": "Sens3_099",
                              "Parent": "Sen2_037",
                              "Child": null,
                              "z_cordinate": 5
                   },
             "z_cordinate": 0
             },
  "z_cordonate": -5
},
{
   "Value": "Sens1_003",
    "Parent": Null,
    "Child": {
        "Value": "Sens2_012",
        "Parent":"Sens1_003",
        "Child" : {
            "Value": "Sens3_054",
            "Parent": "Sen2_012",
            "Child": null,
            "z_cordinate": 5
                  },
        "z_cordinate": 0
             },   
        "z_cordonate": -5
},
.
.
. // till 100th object
{
    "Value": "Sens1_100",
    "Parent": Null,
    "Child": {
        "Value": "Sens2_001",
        "Parent":"Sens1_100",
        "Child" : {
            "Value": "Sens3_021",
            "Parent": "Sen2_001",
            "Child": null,
            "z_cordinate": 5
                  },
    "z_cordinate": 0
             },
    "z_cordonate": -5
}]
```

**NOTE:** I Edited the sample looking object, please review one more time, I changed end braces to look like more an array rather normal object. JSON is secondary, my array should serve my purpose.

**Purpose:**

How Could I access the objects X.parent.child fashion. I've some knowledge but not enough to structure this object.  I'm also planning to access the objects either ways, Grapndparent - Parent - Child and Me - Parent - Grandparent. How could I do that? The objects parent - child relationship should be meaningful rather random and moreover a parent can have more than one child.

Comment: What? Could you rephrase the question or add some detail to make it comprehensible please?

Comment: I've edited question, please check and let me know if you are looking for any further details

Comment: That is not valid Json, to have an array you must use `[,]` not `{}` [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: To me sounds you just want to create a data structure involving objects, not actual JSON. Either way, you need to provide some more information. What exactly are you having problems with? Please post some of your code.

Comment: checkout this package, i think can help you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/customjsonbuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the 'value' key are unique, you can have it as the dictionary key.
So design it like:

```
{
 "Sens1_001": {
               "value": "Sens1_001",
               "parent": null,
               "child": "Sen2_068",
               "z_coordinate": 5
              },
 "Sens2_068": {
               "value": "Sens2_068",
               "parent": "Sens1_001",
               "child": "Sen3_098",
               "z_coordinate": -5
              }
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Once this dictionary 'dict' is ready, if you know the value of the grandparent, then:

```
grandparent = dict[value];
parent = dict[grandparent[child]];
child = dict[parent[child]];
```

Similarly if you know the child's value,

```
child = dict[value];
parent = dict[child[parent]];
grandparent = dict[parent[parent]];
```

Tell me if you dont get it still.

Comment: dict is the JSON dictionary object.

Comment: Ya using the value as key is the solution.

Comment: @GautamJeyaraman, I'm confused in your edit. Could you provide a jsfiddle link regarding the same you were discussing. btw, thanks for your reply. May be it shouldn't be a JSON, but I wanted my object to serve my purpose.

Comment: Please review the question one more time, I've edited according to my requirement

Comment: Ya I saw the edited question and the answer is still the same. I will get you with a jsfiddle sample soon.

Answer (score 0):

Since json is itself a javascript array so you can access json object like you access array;

```
<script>
  var json = [
        {'SMAK' : 1, 'parent': 'i m perent 1', 'child' : 'i m child'}, 
        {'SMAK' : 2, 'parent': 'i m perent 2', 'child' : 'i m child'}, 
        {'SMAK' : 3, 'parent': 'i m perent 3', 'child' : 'i m child'}, 
        {'SMAK' : 4, 'parent': 'i m perent 4', 'child' : 'i m child'}        
      ]
  console.log(json[0]);
  console.log(json[1].parent);
  console.log(json[3]['child']);
</script>
```

So if you know the index you can access any property of that object;

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my objects relationship should be meaningful like parent and child